# Register user in mobile app without e-mail

Tags: ios, android-development

We are currently developing an app for Android and iOS which requires the user to perform a registration. However we don't want the user to go through all this e-mail and password activation link stuff as we aim to let him use the app almost instantly.

The basic idea is that the user enters some mandatory data, clicks a "Register" button and all the verification stuff happens "behind the curtain" (REST via HTTPs). I have heard of some concepts with security tokens but don't know what to look for exactly.

Do you know any techniques for the above? Ideally one which works for both, iOS and Android.

Comment: Have you considered password-less authentication schemes? E.g. I log in to Stack Exchange via my Google account, and not with a password. This means SE doesn't have to validate my identity, and I don't have to trust SE with a password. While Google and Facebook offer custom authentication solutions, these are variants of the more general *OpenID* and *OAuth* protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider SMS verification, which is probably a bit easier to use compared to an email solution.

Basically you'd enter your phone number in the app and you'd receive an SMS with an activation code on said number. In iOS you even see the SMS appear in a "toast", so you don't even need to switch apps if the code is easy enough to enter.

Of course such a solution might have several disadvantages, so you should figure out for yourself if this would fit your needs.